# No Internet after update and restart - Manjaro 5.4

Tags: manjaro

I did a fresh install of Manjaro 5.4 and the internet was working fine. After I run the software update (some 433 packages were updated), I run the following commands to install Nvidia drivers for GeForce 920M (I got this command from another topic from this forum)

sudo mhwd -a pci nonfree 0300
sudo pacman -S downgrade (to downgrade network manager later)

The internet was working fine till then. I restarted the PC and the internet was gone. I tried downgrading network manager but to no avail. The outputs of some commands that were asked for in other topics have been provided below:

```
# ip link
    1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
# ip neighbour (no output whatsoever)
# ip route show (no output whatsoever)
# ping www.google.com 
    ping: www.google.com: Name or service not known
# ping 172.21.0.1 (my router ip)
    ping: connect: Network is unreachable
```

I am now running this browser instance from the bootable drive and the internet is working fine evidently. The pings work fine and the output for 'ip link' is provided below

```
# ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp7s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 20:47:47:a9:d4:45 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

How to I restore internet connection?

Update : I did a fresh install of Manjaro and this time I omitted installing Nvidia drivers. I updated only the packages but still got the same result, so gpu drivers dont have any role in this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can't even ping the local router, it seems that your network interface is down. You need to setup your network with `netctl`.

`netctl` is profile based systemd network manager. ArchWiki has a good and clear document for configuration and usage of it: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Netctl

Don't forget to **enable** your profile after you finish your configuration.(# netctl enable *PROFILE_NAME*)